# Multiple COUNT() in JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, count, left-join

I'm trying to get the number of rows of two different tables with two `LEFT JOIN` in a MySQL query. It works well when I have a `COUNT` on one table like this :

```
SELECT a.title, a.image, COUNT(o.id) AS occasions
FROM activity a 
LEFT JOIN occasion AS o ON a.id = o.activity_id
WHERE a.user_id = 1 
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY a.created_at 
DESC LIMIT 50
```

Here, everything works and I get the good number of "occasions".

But when I try to add an additional `COUNT` with an additional `LEFT JOIN`, the result of the second `COUNT` is wrong :

```
SELECT a.title, a.image, COUNT(o.id) AS occasions, COUNT(au.id) AS users 
FROM activity a 
LEFT JOIN occasion AS o ON a.id = o.activity_id
LEFT JOIN activity_user AS au ON a.id = au.activity_id
WHERE a.user_id = 4 
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY a.created_at 
DESC LIMIT 50
```

Here, I get the good number of "occasions" but "users" seems to be a copy of the "occasions" count, which is wrong.

So my question is, how to fix this query to have the two `COUNT` working together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`COUNT()` counts non-NULL values.  The simple way to fix your query is to use `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
SELECT a.title, a.image,
       COUNT(DISTINCT o.id) AS occasions, COUNT(DISTINCT au.id) AS users 
. . .
```

And this will probably work.  However, it creates an intermediate table that is the Cartesian product of the two tables (for each title).  That could grow very big.  The more scalable solution is to use subqueries and aggregate before joining.

Answer (score 0):

The used left join for activity user limits your result because the DB is not able to found related data. But when you use LEFT OUTER JOIN the  it should return all expected rows and their count.